# React not defined when installing Chakra UI

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I installed Chakra UI using `npm i @chakra-ui/react @emotion/react@^11 @emotion/styled@^11 framer-motion@^6` as suggested. However when I try to run my app now it gives me the following errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')
    at Object.useMemo (react.development.js:1648:1)
    at ThemeProvider (chakra-ui-system.esm.js:35:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20913:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22416:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4161:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4210:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4274:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27405:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26513:1)
```

```
The above error occurred in the <ThemeProvider> component:

    at ThemeProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:20476:27)
    at ChakraProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14271:24)
    at ChakraProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15656:23)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

When stepping into the code in `chakra-ui-system.esm.js`, I see that this line is the issue, and that `React` is not defined in any scope, even though it's imported at the top of the file

```
var computedTheme = React.useMemo(function () {
    return toCSSVar(theme);
  }, [theme]);
```

My app code is very basic, so I am thinking it must be some issues with dependencies.

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ChakraProvider><div></div></ChakraProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I've found a couple questions with this same problem but nobody updated with a resolution (I'm facing this right now)